# Android hardware Keypair Info

Tags: public-key-infrastructure, android, certificate-authority, key-generation

Basically I would like to use Android Keystore to sign requests going to a server from an Android phone. My goal is to have a way of verifying the origin of the request.

Does Android Keystore offer anyway for the receiver of the request to verify that a specific key came from *Android Keystore with a specific hardware/device ID* rather than a keypair generated from OpenSSL, for example.

Comment: @JamesKPolk please add your comment as an answer.

Comment: [Verifying hardware-backed key pairs with Key Attestation](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-key-attestation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doubtful that your signing protocol can convey that metadata. As far as is documented, the public key of a keypair generated in the Android keystore contains no telltale patterns that would identify it as such, nor would such a feature necessarily be desirable from a security standpoint. Finally, such metadata would itself need to authenticated to be relied upon, which creates a very complicated trust structure that would be hard to maintain. – James K Polk Nov 5 at 20:09